# Webpack Invalid configuration object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

I'm receiving some error with webpack like:

> Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a
>   configuration object that does not match the API schema.
>    - configuration.resolve has an unknown property 'extension'. These properties are valid:    object { alias?, aliasFields?,
>   cachePredicate?, cacheWithContext?, concord?, descriptionFiles?,
>   enforceExtension?, enforceModuleExtension?, extensions?, fileSystem?,
>   mainFields?, mainFiles?, moduleExtensions?, modules?, plugins?,
>   resolver?, symlinks?, unsafeCache?, useSyncFileSystemCalls? }    ->
>   Options for the resolver npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

This is my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        publicPath: '/', 
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ['babel-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ['eslint-loader']
        }
        ]
    },
    resolve:{
        extension: ['.js', '.jsx']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is only [extensions](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveextensions) config in webpack

Try to change your code like this

```
resolve:{
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    }
```